# Registering Range Networks Dev Kit / OpenBTS with Restcomm

Tags: voip, gsm, mobicents, restcomm

I'm trying to configure OpenBTS 4 to use Restcomm for SIP registrar, voice and SMS proxy. Looks like OpenBTS has a minimal SIP stack and expects not to be challenged when registering mobile devices as sip clients. I see this question addressed for FreeSwitch:
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/OpenBTS

Can Restcomm be configured to accept registration requests without auth challenge?

### SIP message log:

```
21:52:14,743 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageChannel] (Mobicents-SIP-Servlets-UDPMessageChannelThread-3) Setting SIPMessage peerPacketSource to: /192.168.1.22:5062
21:52:14,749 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (Mobicents-SIP-Servlets-UDPMessageChannelThread-3) <message
from="192.168.1.22:5062" 
to="0.0.0.0:5080" 
time="1417931534736"
isSender="false" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkobtskvtocsucdsglutmh" 
callId="001013e826c0010-e5a7615573939dc7" 
firstLine="REGISTER sip:192.168.1.22 SIP/2.0" 
>
<![CDATA[REGISTER sip:192.168.1.22 SIP/2.0
To: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@192.168.1.22:5080>
From: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@192.168.1.22:5080>;tag=OBTSiciuwjsxgdqsjsrb
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5062;branch=z9hG4bKOBTSkvtocsucdsglutmh;received=192.168.1.22
Call-ID: 001013e826c0010-e5a7615573939dc7
CSeq: 56410 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@127.0.0.1:5062>;expires=5400
P-Preferred-Identity: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@127.0.0.1>
P-PHY-Info: OpenBTS; TA=1 TE=0.294483 UpRSSI=-62.603565 TxPwr=20 DnRSSIdBm=-66 time=1417931534.143
P-Access-Network-Info: 3GPP-GERAN; cgi-3gpp=0010103e8000a
User-Agent: OpenBTS 4.0.0.8025 Build Date Mar 19 2014
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>

21:52:14,755 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.InitialRequestDispatcher] (Mobicents-SIP-Servlets-UDPMessageChannelThread-3) Request event dispatched to RestComm
21:52:14,765 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-31) <message
from="0.0.0.0:5080" 
to="192.168.1.22:5062" 
time="1417931534763"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkobtskvtocsucdsglutmh" 
callId="001013e826c0010-e5a7615573939dc7" 
firstLine="SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication required" 
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication required
To: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@192.168.1.22:5080>;tag=20906605_eef5d580_57a5b08a_e058ce9c-9ea9-4cad-b6c5-372364a3afa9
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5062;branch=z9hG4bKOBTSkvtocsucdsglutmh;received=192.168.1.22
CSeq: 56410 REGISTER
Call-ID: 001013e826c0010-e5a7615573939dc7
From: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@192.168.1.22:5080>;tag=OBTSiciuwjsxgdqsjsrb
Server: TelScale Sip Servlets 7.0.2-SNAPSHOT
Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="192.168.1.22",nonce="36303031356338332d326635622d343"
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>







21:52:45,836 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.UDPMessageChannel] (Mobicents-SIP-Servlets-UDPMessageChannelThread-4) Setting SIPMessage peerPacketSource to: /192.168.1.22:5062
21:52:45,841 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (Mobicents-SIP-Servlets-UDPMessageChannelThread-4) <message
from="192.168.1.22:5062" 
to="0.0.0.0:5080" 
time="1417931565828"
isSender="false" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkobtscdqcajsutpuenhlc" 
callId="001013e826c0010-e5a7615573939dc7" 
firstLine="REGISTER sip:192.168.1.22 SIP/2.0" 
>
<![CDATA[REGISTER sip:192.168.1.22 SIP/2.0
To: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@192.168.1.22:5080>
From: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@192.168.1.22:5080>;tag=OBTSzyvbgcivyilvjqxe
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5062;branch=z9hG4bKOBTScdqcajsutpuenhlc;received=192.168.1.22
Call-ID: 001013e826c0010-e5a7615573939dc7
CSeq: 56411 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@127.0.0.1:5062>;expires=5400
P-Preferred-Identity: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@127.0.0.1>
P-PHY-Info: OpenBTS; TA=1 TE=0.385417 UpRSSI=-66.000000 TxPwr=28 DnRSSIdBm=-48 time=1417931565.071
P-Access-Network-Info: 3GPP-GERAN; cgi-3gpp=0010103e8000a
User-Agent: OpenBTS 4.0.0.8025 Build Date Mar 19 2014
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>

21:52:45,847 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.InitialRequestDispatcher] (Mobicents-SIP-Servlets-UDPMessageChannelThread-4) Request event dispatched to RestComm
21:52:45,851 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-31) <message
from="0.0.0.0:5080" 
to="192.168.1.22:5062" 
time="1417931565849"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkobtscdqcajsutpuenhlc" 
callId="001013e826c0010-e5a7615573939dc7" 
firstLine="SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication required" 
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication required
To: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@192.168.1.22:5080>;tag=12394044_eef5d580_57a5b08a_5b523e6e-471b-4e99-93c0-ad56b68b2b93
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5062;branch=z9hG4bKOBTScdqcajsutpuenhlc;received=192.168.1.22
CSeq: 56411 REGISTER
Call-ID: 001013e826c0010-e5a7615573939dc7
From: <sip:IMSI001010000000002@192.168.1.22:5080>;tag=OBTSzyvbgcivyilvjqxe
Server: TelScale Sip Servlets 7.0.2-SNAPSHOT
Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="192.168.1.22",nonce="32356138316339342d353833652d343"
Content-Length: 0

]]>
</message>
```

Answer (score 2):

Jean Deruelle provided the answer I needed:

https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm/issues/29

> A new config tag authenticate has been added to the restcomm.xml configuration file.
>   Set it to false to disable auth for incoming requests (REGISTER,
>   INVITE, MESSAGE) from SIP Clients  If set to true Restcomm will
>   authenticate users and incoming messages from those users
>   true

```
 <!-- If set to true Restcomm will authenticate users and incoming messages from those users -->

                <authenticate>false</authenticate>
```

Comment: Hi Ivelin, Could you share us where we can edit that property? Thanks.

Comment: The restcomm.xml is generated when the restcomm is running? I edit some properties in the bin/restcomm/restcomm.conf so the properties write the values in the restcom.xml (WEB-INF/restcomm)